# batch syntax error(s)

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to write a batch that will copy the names of the profile folders to a txt file, then take each line (profile) and query ad with it. the two problems I seem to be having are:

1. it says there is a syntax error in the way I wrote my for loop
2. if I break it down for debugging, the loop seems to just set the variable over and over, then use the final value only to perform the commands in the subscripts

```
@echo off

@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "c:\documents and settings"

mkdir c:\pulls
copy \\mint\testfolder\forfiles.exe c:\pulls\
copy \\mint\testfolder\psexec.exe c:\pulls\
rem call \\mint\testfolder\copy.bat c:\pulls\
set queryid=
set checkid=

rem finds all profiles that have been logged into in the last 18 months

c:\pulls\forfiles.exe /p "c:\documents and settings\" /d -540 /c "cmd /c if @ISdir==true deltree @isdir"

dir/b > "c:\documents and settings\profiles.txt"

%queryid% > "c:\documents and settings\tmp.txt"

rem active directory query

:adquery

for /f  "tokens=*" %%n IN ("c:\documents and settings\profiles.txt") do (
    set queryid=%%n
    call :sub
)


goto :end

:sub

c:\pulls\psexec.exe \\computer-u domain\user -p password dsquery user -name %queryid%     > "c:\documents and settings\tmp.txt"
set /p checkid= < "c:\documents and settings\tmp.txt"
del "c:\documents and settings\tmp.txt"


::checks to see if variable is an empty string

if [!%checkid%==!] goto :process1

if [%checkid%==] %queryid% >> c:\documents and settings\final.txt

goto :eof

:process1

c:\pulls\psexec.exe \\computer -u domain\user -p password dsquery user -name %queryid%     -desc *termed* > "c:\documents and settings\tmp.txt"
set /p checkid= < "c:\documents and settings\tmp.txt"
del "c:\documents and settings\tmp.txt"

::checks to see if variable is an empty string

if [!%checkid%==!] goto :amending
if [%checkid%==] goto :process2

goto :eof

:process2

c:\pulls\psexec.exe \\computer -u domain\user -p password dsquery user -name %queryid%     -disabled > "c:\documents and settings\tmp.txt"
set /p checkid= < "c:\documents and settings\tmp.txt"
del "c:\documents and settings\tmp.txt"

::checks to see if variable is an empty string

if [!%checkid%==!] goto :amending

goto :eof

:amending

%checkid% >> "c:\documents and settings\final.txt"

 goto :eof

:end

 notepad.exe "c:\documents and settings\final.txt"

del c:\pulls /y

del "c:\documents and settings\profiles.txt"

del "c:\documents and settings\final.txt"

rem copies selected profiles

rem c:\pulls\copy.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't traced your entire logic to see if you have any other problems. But I have identified the problem with your FOR /F loop.

You are trying to read a file, but your IN() clause is double quoted, so it is interpreted as a string instead of a file name. (Type `FOR /?` for help on FOR command). You want to use double quotes because your path includes spaces, but you need it to be interpreted as a file name - that is what the USEBACKQ option is for!

```
for /f  "usebackq tokens=*" %%n IN ("c:\documents and settings\profiles.txt") do ...
```